# how can a docker container check if it has a capability

Tags: docker

For example, suppose I have a container which needs the NET_ADMIN capability (keepalived as a container for example).

How can I check, when the container is run, that the capability is actually provided, so that I can add a log / throw an error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can commands to check the capabilities

```
$ capsh --print | grep "Current:" | cut -d' ' -f3 | grep -q cap_net_admin
$ echo $?
0

$ capsh --print | grep "Current:" | cut -d' ' -f3 | grep -q cap_net_admins
$ echo $?
1
```

Below command shows all available capabilities for a container

> $ capsh --print | grep "Current:" | cut -d' ' -f3
>       cap_chown,cap_dac_override,cap_fowner,cap_fsetid,cap_kill,cap_setgid,cap_setuid,cap_setpcap,cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw,cap_sys_chroot,cap_mknod,cap_audit_write,cap_setfcap+eip